# environment variable on the line messes up time output

Tags: environment-variables, time

check this out

```
$ time echo 1
1

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

```
$ TESTVAR=TEST time echo 1
1
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1932maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+74minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

I have worked around this by exporting the variable beforehand, but am curious to know why this is.

(ubuntu and bash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you used the `ENV=val` form, you ran a different command than the bash `time` built-in (you ran the GNU time program from `/usr/bin/time`).

If you want to use the shell built-in, use it like this:

```
$ time TESTVAR=TEST echo 1
1

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.004s

$ time TESTVAR=TEST printenv TESTVAR
TEST

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Comment: yeah - or in other words `/usr/bin/time echo 1` gives me the funny looking output as well

Comment: `/usr/bin/time` has an `-f` option to control its format, but it doesn't seem able to format the second values as the `bash` built-in. The `-p` option will let it print them on separate lines, though.

Answer (score 1):

This is closely related to the reason behind a recent question: [Why does a brace command group need spaces after the opening brace in POSIX Shell Grammar?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/526574/70524)

`time`, like `{`, is a reserved word, and a reserved word can't appear after variable assignment.

```
bash-5.0$ foo=bar { echo $foo; }
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
bash-5.0$ foo=bar if true; then echo; fi
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
bash-5.0$ foo=bar if true
bash: if: command not found
```

Since `time` isn't recognized as a reserved word in `TESTVAR=TEST time echo 1`, it undergoes normal command execution, looking for aliases, functions and (in this case, ending up with) external command execution.